Moon phase graphic in TypeScript incorrectly renders waxing and waning phases
I am working on a React/TypeScript component that renders the phases of the moon based on a value between 0 and 1. The issue is that the moon phases are not rendering correctly between the First Quarter and Last Quarter phases. Specifically, the component shows the moon as waxing when it should be waning, and vice versa.
I tried using a Canvas instead of SVG, but it didn't resolve the issue. I also tried to change the calculation for the visible portion of the moon to:
const visiblePortion = Math.cos(normalizedPhase * Math.PI * 2);

But the issue didn't go away. Instead of rendering the moon correctly between 0.25 and 0.75, the light/dark portions of the moon are still reversed for those phases.
Moon Phases on a 0 to 1 Scale
The moon phase is represented as a number between 0 and 1, where:

0: New Moon (0% illumination)
0.125: Waxing Crescent (~25% illumination on the right)
0.25: First Quarter (50% illumination on the right)
0.375: Waxing Gibbous (~75% illumination on the right)
0.5: Full Moon (100% illumination)
0.625: Waning Gibbous (~75% illumination on the left)
0.75: Last Quarter (50% illumination on the left)
0.875: Waning Crescent (~25% illumination on the left)
1: New Moon (0% illumination)

I want the moon to gradually wax between 0 and 0.5 and then wane between 0.5 and 1, but for the phases between 0.25 and 0.75, the light and dark portions are swapped.
Current Code
Here is the code I'm working with:
import React from "react";

interface MoonPhaseProps {
  phase: number;
  moonTexture?: string;
  rotation?: number;
}

const MoonPhase = ({
  phase,
  moonTexture = "/image/moon/moon.svg",
  rotation = 0,
}: MoonPhaseProps) => {
  // Ensure phase is between 0 and 1
  const normalizedPhase = Math.max(0, Math.min(phase, 1));

  console.log(phase, normalizedPhase);

  // Convert phase to radians
  const phaseRadians = normalizedPhase * 2 * Math.PI;

  // Determine if it's a waxing or waning phase
  const isWaxing = normalizedPhase <= 0.5;

  // Calculate the visible portion of the moon
  const visiblePortion = Math.cos(phaseRadians);

  // Adjust the path for waxing and waning phases
  const pathD = isWaxing
    ? `M50,0 A50,50 0 1,1 50,100 A${
        50 * Math.abs(visiblePortion)
      },50 0 1,0 50,0`
    : `M50,0 A50,50 0 1,0 50,100 A${
        50 * Math.abs(visiblePortion)
      },50 0 1,1 50,0`;

  return (
    <svg
      width="100%"
      viewBox="0 0 100 100"
      data-phase={phase}
      style={{
        transform: `rotate(${rotation}deg)`,
        transition: "transform 0.3s ease-in-out",
      }}
    >
      <defs>
        <pattern
          id="moonTexturePattern"
          patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
          width="100"
          height="100"
        >
          <image href={moonTexture} x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
        </pattern>

        <mask id="moonMask">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="white" />
          <path d={pathD} fill="black" />
        </mask>
      </defs>

      {/* Moon texture */}
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="49" fill="url(#moonTexturePattern)" />

      {/* Shading for the dark side of the moon */}
      <circle
        cx="50"
        cy="50"
        r="49"
        fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.7)"
        mask="url(#moonMask)"
      />
    </svg>
  );
};

export default React.memo(MoonPhase);

Here's a sheet (or at least a link to it) showing the moon phases and their values:
moon_phase_explainer
Thanks in advance.

Do you have a working link?

I skipped the path and "constructed" the mask from an ellipse. I don't know if you can use this. In any case, maybe others can.


document.forms.moon.phase.addEventListener('input', e => {
  let e1 = document.getElementById('e1');
  let r1 = document.getElementById('r1');
  let r2 = document.getElementById('r2');
  let val = e.target.value;

  if (val <= .25) {
    r1.setAttribute('fill', '#444');
    r2.setAttribute('fill', 'white');
    e1.setAttribute('fill', '#444');
    e1.setAttribute('rx', 50 - val * 200);
  } else if (val <= .50) {
    r1.setAttribute('fill', '#444');
    r2.setAttribute('fill', 'white');
    e1.setAttribute('fill', 'white');
    e1.setAttribute('rx', (val-.25) * 200);
  } else if (val <= .75) {
    r1.setAttribute('fill', 'white');
    r2.setAttribute('fill', '#444');
    e1.setAttribute('fill', 'white');
    e1.setAttribute('rx', 50 - (val-.50) * 200);
  } else if (val <= 1) {
    r1.setAttribute('fill', 'white');
    r2.setAttribute('fill', '#444');
    e1.setAttribute('fill', '#444');
    e1.setAttribute('rx', (val-.75) * 200);
  }
});
<form name="moon">
  <input name="phase" type="range" min="0" max="1" value="0" step=".01">
</form>
<svg width="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="moonTexturePattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      width="100" height="100">
      <image href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/FullMoon2010.jpg/253px-FullMoon2010.jpg" x="-10" y="-10" width="120" height="120" />
    </pattern>
    <mask id="moonMask">
      <rect id="r1" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="100" fill="#444" />
      <rect id="r2" x="50" y="0" width="50" height="100" fill="#444" />
      <ellipse id="e1" cx="50" cy="50" rx="0" ry="50" fill="black"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="49" fill="url(#moonTexturePattern)"
    mask="url(#moonMask)" />
</svg>
<p><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:FullMoon2010.jpg">Moon image from wikimedia.org</a></p>




It's alright, but I did a mask because by default, the moon should be the background. In your example, part of the moon is not visible (for example, at 0.25, the left half is nothing and the right half is the moon is the moon. I want it to be where the left half is the moon, and the right half is the moon, dimmed.) I couldn't find another way to do this without a mask.

@BestCodes I updated my answer: I replaced all the black fills in the mask with a gray color. Is that more like it?

Thanks a lot for all of your effort! That's much better, though not perfect. Rather than a light overlay, I have a dark one. Here is what my moon looks like at 0.2 (it's still working correctly at this point):
https://i.imgur.com/z90AGCN.png

I think I can just change the color of the white area. Thanks!

So, it looks like the mask is just changing the transparency of the moon image, which means the 'mask' will appear the same color as the background the moon is used on. To make it black, we need to build a black background into the SVG.
Just add another circle in the SVG before the other:   
Thanks for your help!

You want visible portion of the moon to vary from 0 to 100% according to a cos(phase) rule but you have failed to check that your end points in the angle conversion make sense. You seem to want:
cos(0) = 1,  cos (pi/2) = 0, cos(pi) = -1
But you have the line setting the phase angle in radians as multiply by 2*pi :
 const visiblePortion = Math.cos(normalizedPhase * Math.PI * 2);

It should read
 const visiblePortion = Math.cos(normalizedPhase * Math.PI);

Where the sign of the visible portion determines which side to hide.
And then it should either be exactly what you want or the opposite (in which case s/cos/sin/).

Thanks for the answer, but this does not work. The moon is now half lit at 0.5; it should be half lit from one side at 0.25 and from the other at 0.75, not 0.5.
